# How to handle a research identity crisis

Tags: soft-question, gm.general-mathematics, career, advice

I have studied applied math and got a PhD (3yrs) in that field with applications in fluid dynamics. Then in my first postdoc (1.5yrs) I did again a postdoc in applied math but studied applications in biological modeling. Now in my second postdoc (started 2 months ago) I am studying a new application, avalanches. The unifying theme is supposed to be the modeling. My problem is that I am feeling a bit lost, feeling like I have to start again from the beginning in this field (methods, codes et.c). I am completely lost and even if I try to make myself see that as a challenge, I am thinking that I want to go and study computational cosmology but then in this way I will never be enough successful for academia. This is because no ones wants someone that knows a little bit of everything but is expert in nothing. There are other things that I like as topics but not my current postdoc ( I actually got it only because I could not find another position on time to leave the first postdoc). Can you please give me some advice? I would really appreciate it, since I am feeling lost for too long now.

Comment: my advise is the obvious one: explore options outside of academic research.

Comment: If computational cosmology is really what you want to do long-term (is it?), find an expert who would be willing to take you on as a postdoc (or PhD student). In any case, it would be more appropriate to ask your question at: https://academia.stackexchange.com/ Or why not ask https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/
if your current skills are sufficient to start a postdoc in computational cosmology (or if you need to do a new PhD).

Comment: If you would like to continue working in mathematics, my advice would be somewhat different from that given by colleagues above.  I would suggest identifying what your field of strongest expertise/experience is (even if it is not exactly what you currently feel like working on), and turning to an established expert in the field (perhaps one of your advisors) to continue working in that field until you have a reasonable publication record.  You can always return to a new direction (such as computational cosmology that you mentioned) later. Such a course of action would require some patience ...

Comment: ... and humility but those are attributes you may want to develop in any case.

Comment: @MikhailKatz I am thinking about that too. The problem is that I am almost sure that I am not good to continue in mathematics. I am already doing very applied math (applications) and I think to continue in this field or get tenure, I need to compete with very smart people.